# How to add security group rule to multiple security groups

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating one security group rule and want to attach it to multiple security groups. How can I do it? For example:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "test-sg-1" {
  name        = "Test SG 1"
  description = "Test Security Group one"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test-sg-2" {
  name        = "Test SG 2"
  description = "Test Security Group two"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_all" {
  from_port         = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  security_group_id = [aws_security_group.test-sg-1.id, aws_security_group.test-sg-2.id]
  to_port           = 0
  type              = "egress"
  cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

I'm getting error if I try this above way of using a list.

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on main.tf line 76, in resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_all":
│   76:   security_group_id = [aws_security_group.test-sg-1.id, aws_security_group.test-sg-2.id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_security_group.test-sg-1.id will be known only after apply
│     │ aws_security_group.test-sg-2.id will be known only after apply
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "security_group_id": string required.
```

Comment: You could create the security groups using `for_each` and then reference the same rule for each of the security groups.

Comment: @MarkoE How do I reference to the same rule? I cannot define the rule without specifying the security_group_id (REQUIRED) under aws_security_group_rule. Could you please give me a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case using the `for_each` meta-argument [1] might be a good idea to avoid code repetition. So this is what I would do:

```
locals {
  sg_names = ["Test SG 1", "Test SG 2"]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test_sg" {
  for_each    = toset(local.sg_names)
  name        = each.value
  description = each.value
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.test_vpc.id

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress_all" {
  for_each          = aws_security_group.test_sg
  from_port         = 0
  protocol          = "-1"
  security_group_id = each.value.id
  to_port           = 0
  type              = "egress"
  cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

Here the resource chaining is used. You can read more in [2].

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#basic-syntax

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources